# How do you use javascript variables when writing inline CSS styles in a Jade template

Tags: css, node.js, pug

I'm trying to dynamically insert snippets of CSS. Ideally, this would work:

```
style(type='text/css')
    #header a#logo { background:url(constants.logo) no-repeat; }
    @media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {
        #header a#logo { background-image: url(constants.logo_2x); }
    }
```

Unfortunately, constants.logo is /literally/ placed in the DOM. What does work is the following:

```
!= "<style type='text/css'>"
!= "#header a#logo { background:url('"+constants.logo+"') no-repeat; }"
!= "@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {"
!= "    #header a#logo { background-image: url('"+constants.logo_2x+"'); }"
!= "}</style>"
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `#{variable}` to print a variable within an element's text.